# How to declare a generic variable inside a generic method?

Tags: c#, class, generics, methods

I would like to know if it is possible to declare a generic variable inside a generic method. In the following code, I am trying to make "results" a generic variable but I am having a hard time doing so. Therefore, I would appreciate any help on this. Thanks in advance

```
    public static T GetSQLResults<T>(string StoredProcName, Dictionary<string, string> StoredProcParameters)
    {
        var results;

        using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(Settings.ConnStringDb))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(StoredProcName, conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                foreach (var param in StoredProcParameters)
                {
                    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(param.Key, param.Value);
                }

                conn.Open();
                if (typeof(T) == typeof(Boolean))
                {
                    results = cmd.ExecuteReader().HasRows;
                }
                else if (typeof(T) == typeof(DataTable))
                {
                    results.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                }

                //results.Load(cmd.ExecuteReader());
                conn.Close();
            }

            return (T)Convert.ChangeType(results, typeof(T));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Like this: `T results;`

Comment: Yep another vote for `T results;`

Comment: Although there are various other issues here. Firstly, your type can only be `DataTable` or `bool` in this code. Secondly, you call `.Load` on your variable without casting it or even initialising it. And your last line just needs to be `return results;`, no need to convert it.

Comment: The more I look at this code, the more I think that you just need 2 non-generic methods. Generics are useful when you need to do the same thing with different types. You are using it to do different things based on the type.

Comment: I agree with @DavidG. Having to check the generic type the way you're doing has a really bad code smell.

Comment: DavidG is correct. If you are checking the type of a generic, you're probably doing something wrong. Generics are supposed to be **generic**, hence the name.  You are doing something *specific* with each possible type, so simply make two methods.